# sqlsrv_query does not return true

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, database

I am trying to insert form details to the database using microsoft sql. However, even though the query is legit and every column is filled in correctly asnd a database connection is established it doesn't add to the database. I get the echo message Error! nothing was added to the database. :(

```
<?php
// create a database connection
function dbConnect(){
    $dbinfo = array( "Database" => "WEBSHOP", "UID" => "SA", "PWD" => "09starwars09");
    return sqlsrv_connect("DESKTOP-92VILT2\SQLEXPRESS", $dbinfo);
}

// check if there is a database connection.
if(dbConnect()) {echo 'There is a database connection established';}
else {echo 'Database connection is not established';}

// check if all for details are filled in.
if(!empty($_POST['UserName']) && !empty($_POST['Password']) && !empty($_POST['Voornaam']) && !empty($_POST['Achternaam']) && !empty($_POST['Emailadres']) && !empty($_POST['Straatnaam']) && !empty($_POST['Huisnummer']) && !empty($_POST['Plaatsnaam']) && !empty($_POST['Postcode']) && !empty($_POST['Telefoon'])){
    $Gebruikersnaam = $_POST['UserName'];
    $Wachtwoord = $_POST['Password'];
    $geslacht = $_POST['Aanhef'];
    $Voornaam = $_POST['Voornaam'];
    $tussenvoegsels = $_POST['Tussenv'];
    $Achternaam = $_POST['Achternaam'];
    $EmailAddress = $_POST['Emailadres'];
    $Straatnaam = $_POST['Straatnaam'];
    $Huisnummer = $_POST['Huisnummer'];
    $Plaats = $_POST['Plaatsnaam'];
    $Postcode = $_POST['Postcode'];
    $Telefoon = $_POST['Telefoon'];

    // insert form information to the database.
    // yes this is unsave but it is just for testing purposes.
    $sql = "INSERT INTO GEBRUIKER  ([GEBRUIKERSNAAM], [VOORNAAM], [TUSSENVOEGSEL], [ACHTERNAAM], [STRAATNAAM], [HUISNUMMER], [POSTCODE], [WOONPLAATS], [EMAIL], [SEXE], [WACHTWOORD])
            VALUES ('".$Gebruikersnaam."', '".$Voornaam."','".$tussenvoegsels."','".$Achternaam."','".$Straatnaam."','".$Huisnummer."','".$Postcode."','".$Plaats."','".$EmailAddress."','".$geslacht."','".$Wachtwoord."')";

    // add to the database <--- This part doesn't work!
    if(sqlsrv_query(dbConnect(), $sql)) {
        echo 'There was an item added to the database!';
    } else{
        echo 'Error! nothing was added to the database. :(';
    }
} else{
    echo 'Not all items are form filled in!';
}
```

Comment: Add `die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));` after `echo 'Error! nothing was added to the database. :('` What it will show?

Comment: :(Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => 22018 [SQLSTATE] => 22018 [1] => 245 [code] => 245 [2] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'test' to data type int. [message] => [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 11 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'test' to data type int. ) )

Comment: There is a field that has `int` type in your table, and you put there `test` value!

Comment: It may be `Huisnummer`, `Postcode` or `Telefoon`. Just guessing :)

Comment: Ah that's right ! But now i get this  'String or binary data would be truncated.' thank you for the help !

Comment: That means something you `POST` is much longer than table can handle! My pleasure! And good luck!